# Angular 2 Material can't load style

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I'm starting to develop an web app in Angular using the Angular Material library for the interface. But I'm getting an error when trying to import a prebuilt theme. In order to import it, I added `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css">` to my `index.html` file but when i run `ng serve` I cannot get the file.

Comment: Show us your project files structure.

Comment: you'll have to add `../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css` to the `styles` in `.angular-cli.json` file

Comment: Tryed that but didn't work either

Comment: I've got this exact same problem.  I imported the styles like the material documentation stated to, but none of the colors or styles are coming through.  Did you figure out how to fix this?

Comment: No, I had to create a custom theme and then It worked. With the pre built theme, the import doesn't work for me

Comment: guys, same problem can you guys help?

Answer (score 13):

If you are using `angular-cli` follow their [steps for including Angular-Material](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/include-angular-material.md).

Ensure you have the below imports in `src/styles.css`

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
@import '~https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';
```

It's slightly different to what `angular-material` suggest on their own *Getting Started* site but it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Check that your path is correct. I had the same problem and I fixed the path:
Mine is

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css">
```

Comment: I have this same problem, did you fix?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find any solution just add angular material again. It won't affect your code but add the CSS. Don't forget to re-start the angular server.

```
ng add @angular/material
```

Comment: When i run this again still problem is same ,and also I am not able to find style.css under src folder