# MatSelectModule style is not working accurately Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-material-6

I'm new to angular(6). I was using **MatSelectModule** in my form. It is working fine but Its style is weird like options are placed somewhere at the bottom of the page. I have tried in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50328091/angular-material-6-doesnt-shows-form-styles) way, but failed. Help me to identify the reason. Here are some lines, you will require to analyse. Thank you.

In XYZ.component.html

```
             <mat-form-field>
                <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" formControlName="toppings" multiple>
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
```

In XYZ.component.ts

```
toppingList: string[] = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];
```

In app.component.ts

```
import { MatInputModule, MatButtonModule, MatSelectModule, MatIconModule } from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatIconModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you include the pre-built theme css in your app?

According to the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) you can use one of the pre-built themes or define a custom theme

You can include a theme file directly into your application from @angular/material/prebuilt-themes

Available pre-built themes:

- deeppurple-amber.css
- indigo-pink.css
- pink-bluegrey.css
- purple-green.css

If you're using Angular CLI, this is as simple as including one line in your styles.css file:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

Alternatively, you can just reference the file directly. This would look something like:

```
<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Glad i could help :)